# user regex in $nin mongo

Tags: mongodb, meteor, aggregation-framework

I can't make work the following regex in the aggregation. I read lots of example but it's not working. What I want is to exclude words that has 3 or less characters(example: 1 a2 aaa a-). However they still appear.

This is my regex (I think it's correct) `\b\w?\w?\w?\b`.

And here is the aggregation:

```
Meteor.publish("topics", function () {
  ReactiveAggregate(this, Articles, [
    {
      $project: {
              topic: { $split: ["$title", " "] },

              article: "$$ROOT"
      }
    },
    {
      $unwind: {
              path: "$topic"
      }
    },
    {
      $match: {
              topic: { $nin: ["sports", "\b\w?\w?\w?\b"] }
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
              _id: "$topic",
              count: { $sum: 1 },
              articles: { $push: "$article" }
      }
    }
  ], { clientCollection: "clientTopic" });
});
```

Example:

```
    /* Article 1 */
{
    "_id" : "SB4mKAxaBijQXnS73",
    "title" : "Messi signs new contract with Barcelona"
}
/* Article 2 */
{
     "_id" : "rhqioBkePzGCrRFLp",
     "title" : "Messi has 30 years old"
 }
/* Article 3 */
{
      "_id" : "X6LochRZw32op39W8",
      "title" : "President of Argentina visits Messi"
}
```

I want to get a collection like:

```
Messi ==> {_id: "Messi", articles: [Article 1, Article 2, Article 3], count: 3 }
signs ==> {_id: "signs", articles: [Article 1], count: 1 }
contract ==> {_id: "contract", articles: [Article 1], count: 1 }
with ==> {_id: "with", articles: [Article 1], count: 1 }
Barcelona  ==> {_id: "Barcelona", articles: [Article 1], count: 1 }

years  ==> {_id: "years", articles: [Article 2], count: 1 }

President  ==> {_id: "President", articles: [Article 3], count: 1 }
Argentina  ==> {_id: "Argentina", articles: [Article 3], count: 1 }
visits     ==> {_id: "visits", articles: [Article 3], count: 1 }
```

As you can see, the words `new`, `has`, `30`, `old`, `of` should not appear because their lengths are 3 chars or less.

The articles with the word `sports` in theirs title are not contain in the collection, however the one that match the regex are contain.

Comment: Can you show an example of documents that should be included and those that should be excluded? That would make it clearer what the query condition should in fact be.

Comment: The regex looks wrong anyway. Should be ``/\b\w{3}\b/``

Comment: @NeilLunn I edited my first post adding an example. I want to eliminate "noise" or "stop" words (the, in, an, a, it, etc...) otherwise they'll always rank at the top.

Comment: @NeilLunn Why? Just add the example to represent which documents should appear in the collection. I change the regex to what you said but that words still appearing. It's like it doesn't match anything.

Comment: Dude. You want a [`$text`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/) search and not using `$split` or any of this at all. MongoDB already does this, so you don't need to reinvent it.

Comment: @NeilLunn My documents has more than the title field, so how can I use $text to search only in that field, using also the regex?  I never use it

Comment: Because you don't need the `$regex` and "text searches" are defined by their "index creation". As soon as you mention "stop words" it's obvious you want a text search. Read up about it instead. Using aggregate here is the completely wrong approach, and a performance hog.

Answer (score 0):

Each element in the array reads with ^ preceding the word, e.g. ['^work', '^accus', '^planet']

OR

var words = [/hello/, /^world/];// array of regex
db.getCollection('word collection').find({"word" : {$in : words}});

Comment: you say that I should precede the regex with a `^` ? I do that like this: 

`{
      $match: {
              topic: { $nin: ["sports", "^\b\w?\w?\w?\b"] }
      }
    },`

but still getting those words in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to exclude words whose lengths are 3 or less than 3, then you can use /\w{4,}/

```
Meteor.publish("topics", function () {
  ReactiveAggregate(this, Articles, [
    {
      $project: {
              topic: { $split: ["$title", " "] },

              article: "$$ROOT"
      }
    },
    {
      $unwind: {
              path: "$topic"
      }
    },
    {
      $match: {
              topic: { $nin: ["sports", "\w{4,}"] }
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
              _id: "$topic",
              count: { $sum: 1 },
              articles: { $push: "$article" }
      }
    }
  ], { clientCollection: "clientTopic" });
});
```

You can use this link for test regular expression  https://regex101.com/